# Drop Down CSS not working (Laravel Blades)

Tags: html, css

I have a view in which I am using some drop downs like
[image]

[Access Link](http://54.202.231.112/aplica_student/public/search?searchtype=consultants)

I am unable to show border bottom, I have tried to give border-bottom or border definition manually in that elements CSS but couldn't fix. Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that it has no bottom border, but it is just not being shown by your browser.

Your button has a height of 40px. But it is also contained in a div that has a height of 40px and a `box-sizing` of `border-box`.

Based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values), when using `border-box` with `box-sizing`, the height allocated to the content (in this case, your `button`) is reduced after considering the border and padding attributes of the element (in this case, your `div`). I just do not know why the content appears to be being rendered in a way that it overlays the bottom border of your container div.

Note that the `box-sizing` property in your CSS is applied to all elements, including `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

You can resolve your issue and show the bottom border if you do any of the following:

- Reduce the height of the `button` element (e.g., set `.ms-choice` to have height of 38px).
- Increase the height of the container `div` (e.g. set to 42px). This will just mis-align your dropdown menus with your search input.
- Change the container `div` to have a `box-sizing` of `content-box`.
- Change the background-color of your button to transparent and put the white background color on your `div.ms-parent.form-control`. (I added this option to show that the `button`' is actually being rendered such that it overlays the bottom border of the containing `div`.)

Comment: I removed the height, now it works perfectly, thanks Frank